# React Webpack is not working in IE11 in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

My application is not rendering in IE11 in production(Works in chrome) . I am using the react webpack  and  Getting the error like this in chrome console because of webpack in production . Suggest me to debug this bug

> SCRIPT1002: Syntax error vendor.js (1,268483)

Version

> ```
>   "webpack": "^2.2.1",
>   "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.1",
>   "react": "^15.4.1",
> ```

Comment: Please clarify the "react webpack" term. Is it your environment setup or you are using the "create-react-app" (I have used the later and it's working fine with IE11). Thanks.

Comment: It is my environment setup

Comment: babel, babel-polyfill ?

Comment: I am using babel-polyfil

Comment: works in Chrome but not IE? This will definitely boil down to es6 support. I'd suggest combing through your project for feature usages and cross reference the [ie11 es6 support table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#ie11). You likely need additional polyfills...

Comment: add the babel transpiller as well.

Comment: yes i added that  . If i not added , this will not work in chrome . For me  working good in Chrome . Issue in IE11